# Problems deploying JAXWS with Tomcat 7.0.35

Tags: java, soap, tomcat7, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

we are running ubuntu 13.04 + Tomcat/7.0.35 + java 1.7.0_51-b00.
The setup was successfully running for months. 
Now we added a SOAP endpoint using jax-ws 2.2.8 and the application does not deploy on the server anymore, saying

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/v014]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

Mar 31, 2014 12:26:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/v014.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/v014]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

adding the following maven dependencies makes the webapp run locally through eclipse/tomcat7, but does not solve the problem on the remote server.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.8</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
     <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
   <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
   <artifactId>gmbal-api-only</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0-b003</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.ha</groupId>
   <artifactId>ha-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.9</version>
  </dependency>
```

we have also tried to manually add the jars

```
jaxb-impl.jar jaxb-core.jar ha-api.jar gmbal-api-only.jar jaxws-api.jar jaxws-rt.jar management-api.jar policy.jar stax-ex.jar streambuffer.jar
```

to both Tomcat's lib and/or the webapp's WEB-INF folders with no effect.

Also tried downgrading all the way to jax-ws 2.1 --> same error.

Help or ideas are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @rustyx suggests should work. but I had the same issue using OpenJDK 1.7, the solution was to add the following dependencies on my pom.xml

```
<!-- JAX-WS Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
                <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
        <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmbal-api-only</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-b003</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.ha</groupId>
        <artifactId>ha-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope that helps,
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to run JAX-WS is already included in the standard java 1.7 JVM.

Only include the JARs that are custom to your application.

I suggest to remove anything that relates to jaxws, jaxb, policy, stax and streambuffer from your bundled JARs.

Comment: Tomcat does not has access to these jars in the JVM. Tomcat only runs on JRE. and these jars are outside of JRE.

Comment: Java SE (Oracle's JRE) includes everything needed to run JAX-WS services since version 6. [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jax-ws-2-141894.html)

Comment: Agreed. My comment is incorrect. JAX-WS is available as API and thus can be directly imported into code. Inclusion of no other jar is required.